# Calculate the probabilities of the same coulor appearing in a row

Tags: probability

I am doing some experiments using the probabilities on a roulette.

I found this link: http://www.roulettestar.com/probability.php

Where you see "Same even money bet result in a row probability." the page reports the probabilities in percentage of the same coulor appearing in a row.

I am really not getting how is that calculated. Does anyone know how that site calculated that percentages? What is the math formula behind?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability for a color is $18/37 =\sim 48.6\%$. To get the same (given) color $n$ times consecutively is simply $(18/37)^n$.